# Leaflet Vector Grid - cancel tile requests when not in viewport

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles, leaflet-plugins

I use Leaflet with the Leaflet.VectorGrid plugin to serve my own vector tiles (created with pg_tileserv). The tiles are automatically reloaded/updated when the user zooms in/out or is panning the map.

**Problem**: When the user is e.g. panning a lot and then stops, a lot of tiles are requested for all the areas the user panned through, although these tiles are not in the current viewport and cannot be visualized/seen. The problem is that this prevents the tiles being loaded that are actually needed (in the current viewport).

**Possible solutions already tried:**

- The Leaflet.VectorGrid extends L.GridLayer (https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html). L.GridLayer has the options `updateWhenIdle`, `updateWhenZooming` and `updateInterval`, but none of these works.

There is also an issue on GitHub, but I do not understand if it resulted in any solution? https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/issues/136

Are there any options or solutions so that the requests for the tiles can be cancelled/aborted, that are not needed?